# fn:current-dateTime() not returning milliseconds

Tags: datetime, xpath, xquery, osb

I am using the fn:current-dateTime() function to take system date and time. It is giving date format as 2019-04-24T10:09:20.633+03:00. 
But some times it not returns milliseconds and giving like--2019-01-31T09:54:33+02:00

we need milliseconds part also, please let us know why it happen and how to overcome this problem.

{ fn:current-dateTime() }

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it happened when the milliseconds part is equal to 0. I haven't reproduced yet but I've encountered a two-digits milliseconds part when it was < 100 (`2019-04-24T08:39:53.36Z`), is it also something you would like to avoid?

Answer (score 2):

The XQuery Engine you are using is allowed not to provide milliseconds when they are equal to zero.

If you always want them, you should then call format-dateTime().

Comment: Thanks for the your answer.. 
This Function format-dateTime() is not supports in Xqurey..is there any other function/process to retrieve milliseconds even it is equal to zero..?

Comment: fn:seconds-from-dateTime() is returning an xs:decimal value which can be formatted with fn:format-number()

Answer (score 2):

Is your problem that the date/time is not precise enough for your needs, or is the problem that the string representation does not include any fractional seconds?

If the problem is precision, then you might be using the wrong function, because current-dateTime() returns the same value throughout the running of a query and the system isn't required to return a very precise value.

If the problem is the formatting of the string representation (i.e. you'd be happy if it had ".000" added to the end), then (a) your expectations of the spec are wrong, and (b) you can get what you want using seconds-from-dateTime().